# Liferay hook CDI

Tags: liferay, hook, cdi

I am developing a service hook for Liferay, and I want to use an external EJB to do the business logic for me. Is there any way to inject a bean to a service class?

Here is my code:

```
public class MyUserService extends UserServiceWrapper {

    //I want a bean injected
    @Inject
    MyBean myBean;

    public MyUserService(UserService userService) {
        super(userService);
    }

    @Override
    public User addUserWithWorkflow(/* all kind of parameters */)
            throws PortalException, SystemException {
        User user = super.addUserWithWorkflow(/* all parameters passes here //);

        //do my business logic here
        myBean.userRegistered(user);

        return user;
    }
}
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If the bean is already loaded in the AppContext (use a hook-spring.xml file) you can use

```
Object bean = com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.PortletBeanLocatorUtil.locate(
       "bean id", "class")
```

Is that what you were looking for?